# Wrong Result after Yes/No Button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently adding a relatively simple user decision Box to my excel file, but there seems to be some issue that I can't find.

The basic idea is that if a user Clicks Yes everything is ok and a message box pops up telling him that and if he/she clicks no he should input a calendar date which should be added to a sheet.

I already have issues with my current code where the date-adding part isn't even integrated yet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

MsgBox "Volume already in rolling forecast?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Rolling Forecast Integration"    
If Answer = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "O.K", vbOKOnly, "O.K"        
Else
    MsgBox "Please specify", vbQuestion, "Contact Me"
End If    

End Sub
```

When I click Yes it should the OK Message box, right? Well it always displays the "Please specify" MsgBox and I don't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also shorten down your code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If MsgBox("Volume already in rolling forecast?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Rolling Forecast Integration") = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "O.K", vbOKOnly, "O.K"
    Else
        MsgBox "Please specify", vbQuestion, "Contact Me"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set-up `Answer` with the result coming from the `MsgBox`.

Modify your first line of :

```
MsgBox("Volume already in rolling forecast?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Rolling Forecast Integration")
```

To:

```
Answer = MsgBox("Volume already in rolling forecast?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Rolling Forecast Integration")
```

Comment: OP might also consider declaring Answer as variable as well - e.g. As vbMsgBoxResult